# Missing index signature in type Array<string> with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

**I am seeing this error with TypeScript:**

[image]

The code itself just looks like this:

```
let fn =  function (transformPaths: Array<string>, cb: Function) {

    async.mapLimit(transformPaths, 5, function (t: string, $cb: Function) {

         // ....

    }, cb);

};
```

The error message is:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'Dictionary<{}>'. Index signature is missing in type 'string[]'.

How can I correct this? As you can see from the screenshot, the typings from the async library do not like a plain array of strings being passed as the first argument to async.mapLimit, but why?

**I am 99% certain I need to add an index signature to the array of strings, but how do I do that?**

Here is something that "compiles" but I don't know if it's correct (this doesn't seem to be helping anyone):

```
export interface ISumanTransformPaths extends Array<string> {
  [index:string]: Object
}
```

now when I use `(transformPaths: ISumanTransformPaths)`, then it compiles, but I am not sure if this correct.

Comment: You need a different type. You have an array, and you need what seems to be a js object (i.e.: `{ key1: "value1", key2: "value2" }`)

Comment: @NitzanTomer I don't think so - I think async library will accept an Iterable, which can be either an Object or Array. But I agree, it's not very clear.

Comment: I don't know this `async` library, but usually `Dictionary` means key/value. Can you share a link to the definition file for it?

Comment: Yes I agree with you, I am 99% certain that Dictionary means key/value. I actually now believe firmly that the type def for async is incorrect. It should be Iterable<T> not Dictionary<{}>.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/async

Comment: I am still looking for answer to this damn problem: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/24469

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Nitzan for confirming that `@types/async` is probably correct. This solved the problem:

**before:**

```
 let fn = function (transformPaths: Array<string>, cb: Function) {

    async.mapLimit(transformPaths, 5, function (t: string, cb: Function){

     // problem...does not compile

    }, cb);
 }
```

**after:**  (look carefully, there is just one change)

```
  let fn = function (transformPaths: Array<string>, cb: AsyncResultArrayCallback<Error,Array<any>>) {

        async.mapLimit(transformPaths, 5, function (t: string, cb: Function) {

        // now it compiles!

        }, cb);

   };
```

Answer (score 3):

The [signatures for this method](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/async/index.d.ts#L112) are:

```
mapLimit<T, R, E>(arr: T[] | IterableIterator<T>, limit: number, iterator: AsyncResultIterator<T, R, E>, callback?: AsyncResultArrayCallback<R, E>): void;
mapLimit<T, R, E>(arr: Dictionary<T>, limit: number, iterator: AsyncResultIterator<T, R, E>, callback?: AsyncResultArrayCallback<R, E>): void;
```

So it can work with a `Dictionary` or an array/`IterableIterator`.
I'm not sure why the compiler infers the 2nd signature instead of the first, but maybe because the `callback` you pass it should be the 4th argument, while the 3rd needs to be an iterator.

Comment: thanks Nitzan, I figured it out, I added an answer showing what works for me.

Comment: I am still looking for answer to this damn problem: github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/24469